# How to print a page along with all CSS formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, printing-web-page

I am doing a print functionality. The problem I am getting is that the page, which is being printed, is not retaining it's CSS formatting. I am getting plain text on print without CSS. Does anyone know how to print page with all it's CSS formatting unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the site you are trying to print has a custom stylesheet for printing. This stylesheet is often simplified and made to fit onto a printable page. I don't think there is much you can do about it unless you have the ability to modify or remove the print CSS file.

[Intro to print style sheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

Example markup for one.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Perhaps there is some way to use javascript to programmatically remove the style sheet, but I am not sure.

Comment: do you mean to say..i need to create another stylesheet called print.css for print media?isn't there any other way instead of creating seperate stylesheet for printing?

Comment: I am saying that sites print with all CSS by default. If you aren't printing with CSS then the page already has a print CSS sheet (or perhaps `@media="screen"` defined which is preventing the styles from coming through. I guess there is a remote possiblity that there is a browser setting that does this. You could test by trying to print from a separate browser. If you provide a link to the site in question someone you could tell you for certain.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms for anyone who is still wondering, you can have a CSS stylesheet that has 'media="screen" ' in the link markup as follows:

```
<link id="Link1" href="../Styles/MainStyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" media="screen" />
```

this will style what is seen in the browser screen.

You can also have another CSS stylesheet that has 'media="print" ' in the link markup as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/print_voucher.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

this will style what is seen when a user views a Print Preview / when it is printed on the paper.

If you put something like:

```
.inprintdisabled
{
 display: none;
}
```

in your print_voucher.css file. Everywhere in your HTML code where there is a

```
<div class="inprintdisabled">
```

it will show the contents of that div in the browser window but WILL NOT print out / show it in a print preview window.

Likewise, if you put

```
.inprintOnly
{
 display:none;
}
```

in your MainStyleSheet and

```
<div class="inprintOnly">
```

in your HTML code, you can have objects (text, images, etc) that don't appear on your browser screen , but will appear when print previewed / printed out.

Hope this helps.